# Capturing db2 command's return code in shell script

Tags: bash

```
x=`su - db2inst1 -c "db2 get dbm cfg" |grep KEYSTORE_LOCATION | awk '{print $5}'`
rc="$?"
echo "${rc}"
```

this echos a 0.

If I forcefully execute a wrong command

```
x=`su - db2inst1 -c "db get dbm cfg" |grep KEYSTORE_LOCATION | awk '{print $5}'`
rc="$?"
echo "${rc}"
```

this gives me an error:

```
-bash: db: command not found
```

but still gives a 0 return code. I think its for the assignment. But how do I evaluate for the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set -o pipefail
```

By default the return value of a pipeline is the exit code from the last command—here, `awk '{print $5}'`.  Turn on `pipefail` to have the pipeline fail if any command fails, not just the last.

Comment: How do we unset this?

Comment: `set +o pipefail`